# How can I choose both date and time using calender in custom option in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, datetime

I am making an e-commerce website using `magento` and came across situation where I had to choose `delivery date`.For delivery date I use `product custom option`. To display calendar I

`Set Use JavaScript Calendar as Yes` in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Date & Time Custom Options.`

Now I have to choose both `date and time`, currently it gives only date.

How can I choose both date and time using calender in custom option?

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap-datetimepicker=> datetimepicker.css, bootstrap-datepicker.js
Having Date and Time Options In One Datepicker.